# Grails: disable Spring Security Core on certain paths

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

How do I set up Spring Security Core in a way that calls to a certain pattern (such as /api/**) are not filtered?

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/api/**': '',
'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS',
]
```

doesn't work, since it will try to resolve the bean ''.

Is there anything other than the nasty workaround with 'JOINED_FILTERS,-filter1,-filter2,...'

How are static resources being excluded from Spring Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the anonymous filter to your filter chain.
If you followed the grails spring security rest configuration tutorial you probably got the following code:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ]
]
```

Note that you have "**-anonymousAuthenticationFilter**" , which removes this filter  from your filter chain.
By removing this part (-anonymousAuthenticationFilter) from your code,  this filter will back to your filter chain, 
so you can use the **@Secured("permitAll")** or **@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])** again.

My final filter chain map was the following and worked like a charm.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ]
]
```

Add this to you logback.groovy in the development environment when you need to see more details about the authentication process

```
logger("org.springframework.security", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("grails.plugin.springsecurity", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("org.pac4j", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)

logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false)
root(ERROR, ['STDOUT', 'FULL_STACKTRACE'])
```

The same idea applies if you do not use spring security rest.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement a simple non-authentication filter::

```
class NonAuthenticationFilter  extends GenericFilterBean {

    void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Define it in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    nonAuthFilter(NonAuthenticationFilter)
}
```

And configure your url pattern:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'nonAuthFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS',
]
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/api/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! why do I need grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap? that's optional, right? Does it conflict with my @Secured annotations?

Comment: this is one of securityConfigType. I used interceptUrlMap just for example. It's up you which method to use. More info [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/api/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

this is not enough, it  should be added with this line :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
```

## NOTE :

### Previous versions:

```
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.*
```

### New version :

```
  grails.plugin.springsecurity.*//plugin without s
```