# grails spring security rest plugin how to skip url from authentication

Tags: spring, rest, grails

I am using spring security rest plugin as well as core in my grails app,i want to have some calls those can be accessed without authentication and for this i am adding @Secured('permitAll') on action but it is not working,it is still asking for token.
I have also tried '/api/getdata':  ['permitAll'] in config.groovy,but no result!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the anonymous filter to your filter chain.
If you followed the grails spring security rest configuration tutorial you probably got the following code:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ]
]
```

Note that you have "-anonymousAuthenticationFilter" , which removes this filter  from your filter chain.
By removing this part (-anonymousAuthenticationFilter) from your code,  this filter will back to your filter chain, 
so you can use the @Secured("permitAll") or @Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']) again.

My final filter chain map was the following and worked like a charm.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ]
]
```

Add this to you logback.groovy in the development environment when you need to see more details about the authentication process

```
logger("org.springframework.security", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("grails.plugin.springsecurity", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("org.pac4j", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)

logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false)
root(ERROR, ['STDOUT', 'FULL_STACKTRACE'])
```

The same idea applies if you do not use spring security rest.
Same answer I gave in another post, didn't knew what to do.

Answer (score 0):

use static mapping..

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/':                              ['permitAll'],
        '/user/someaction1':             ['permitAll'],
        '/user/someaction1':                 ['permitAll'],
]
```

Comment: whether you specified the domain class in grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName

Comment: Yes,rest security is working ,my question is about to skip authentication part from certain calls like i have a call api/getData ,i want this call to be served without authentication i.e no need of log in.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but this should help, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091281)