# Grails/security: on the motivation for implementing a NonAuthFilter

Tags: grails, spring-security

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079122/grails-disable-spring-security-core-on-certain-paths)

Why would one favour implementing a non-authenticating filter on a url, over allowing it under `staticRules` w/`permitAll`? Is there any difference, from a security standpoint?

They seem to me as achieving the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a non-zero overhead from doing security checks. In most cases the cost is small, but depending on what gets checked it could be more resource-intensive, and even if each individual request's cost is small, the cumulative cost can be significant, especially when you consider that in many applications the security checks run for every request, including the favicon, and all CSS, JS, and image files.

There's also a cost to repopulating the `SecurityContext` with an `Authentication`; often this is configured from data stored in the HTTP session, but it could be more involved and even require database access or a remote call.

There's no direct support for this in the plugin and you need to use a workaround like in the link you showed, but I'm planning on adding support for 2.0 final; see [this JIRA issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-270).